# Regex match when not contains word

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have a question but I can't seem to figure it out.  I have been referenceing this article: 
[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

I am trying to match a URL if the URL doesn't contain 2 dashes:

Match = `/test-doc.html`

Non-Match = `/test-doc--help.html`

I have this which works to match and non-match: `/(?<a>.(?!\-\-))*\.html`

But the group "a" only gets 1 letter vs everything looking back.  I would want group "a" to be "test-doc" rather than just the "c" at the end.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try a pattern like this:

```
/(?<a>(?!.*--).*)\.html
```

This will match a literal `/` followed by zero more of any character, captured in group `a`, (but *only* if that sequence does not contain a literal `--`), followed by a literal `.html`.

For example:

```
Dim pattern As String = "/(?<a>(?!.*--).*).html"
Regex.Match("/test-doc-help.html", pattern).Groups("a").Value  // "test-doc-help"
Regex.Match("/test-doc--help.html", pattern).Groups("a").Value // ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try your expression in this website

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

And also i think you should use this expression

```
"\/.*.html"
```